# Focusing box on QRCode scanner on iOS 7

Tags: ios7, avfoundation, qr-code, barcode-scanner

I'm investigating if it's possible to implement the same functionalities of `ZBar` library with iOS 7 api.

Everything was good so far thanks to this [tutorial](http://www.renaudpradenc.com/?p=453).

However, I now want to have a green box shown on the screen whenever the camera detects a `QRCode`. The green box is supposed to wrap around the `QRCode`.

From the delegate of `AVCaptureMetadataOutput`, I can grab `AVMetadataObject` but the bounds getting from this object is always very small which is not correct, given the fact that my `QRCode` is very big on the screen.

Anyone has any ideas on how to achieve the green focusing box?

P/S: I came across the documentation and couldn't understand this line "**If the metadata originates from video, bounds 
    may be expressed as scalar values from 0. - 1.**". This is for the bounds property of AVMetadataObject

Answer (score 0):

You can look at this [tutorial](http://www.ama-dev.com/iphone-qr-code-library-ios-7/) for qrCode scanning using iOS 7.

Answer (score 0):

I had to do the same thing in my scanner app. Here is a [link](http://www.shinobicontrols.com/blog/posts/2013/10/11/ios7-day-by-day-day-16-decoding-qr-codes-with-avfoundation) that I found very useful and pretty much answered all my questions.

He goes step by step from setting up the scanner to adding the bounding box.